# getting maximum and minimum values from specific columns

Tags: r

my data has decimal values from which i need to get min and max value.using `apply(x,2,min)` returns the correct scientific value. However i want the value in decimal format itself.
kindly suggest

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve]

Comment: Copy paste your code so we can help you out further.

Comment: Please provide problem in minimal reproducible form, i.e. so that anyone else can *easily* copy it from your post & paste it into their session & see the results.  All code, library statements & inputs must be provided & if large they need to be cut down to the minimal size that will still illustrate problem.  Post output of `dput(whatever)` to show input data reproducibly.  For more info on how to pose a question see (1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example (2)  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (3) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you need to suppress the scientific notation, `options(scipen=999); apply(x,2,min)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `sapply()`? `Sapply()` is a user-friendly version and wrapper of `lapply` by default returning a vector, matrix or, if `simplify = "array"`, an array if appropriate

> i want the value in decimal format itself

Run `options(scipen=10)` before running other code. If it doesn't help, replace 10 with higher value (up to 999).